# Ssh connection in ubuntu in Oracle vm throwing error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

**Hi All,
Please let me know what to be done here. I am trying to install Hadoop in Ubuntu.The ssh connectivity is throwing error.
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1) but 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                  Recommends: ncurses-term but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**buntu@ubuntu:/etc$ ifconfig**
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:3a:a6:f3
          inet addr:192.168.0.112  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe3a:a6f3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11839138 (11.8 MB)  TX bytes:1448354 (1.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:217643 (217.6 KB)  TX bytes:217643 (217.6 KB)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install openssh-server

ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ''
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh localhost
```

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
 I followed all your process but stil the same issues. Can you please help me out.

Comment: sudo apt-get install openssh-server this command is working fine

Comment: sudo iptables -L,

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT execute both command

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
Some packages could not be installed. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1) but 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                  Recommends: ncurses-term but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: buntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused